# React native interval, Can't make it right way

Tags: react-native, intervals

Hi I'm just trying up setstate a component with interval.I put interval code in `componentdidmount` and clear it in `componentWillUnmount`.

It should stops intervalling when user navigates another screen but console logs says it continues.
Also i want to works this in every 1 second but when i put interval time as `1000` it works in 3 second

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text:'',
    };

    this._interval = null;
  }
componentDidMount() {
   if (!this._interval) {
  console.log('this._interval',this._interval)

      var endNew = new Date(this.props.end); 

      var distance = endNew.getTime() - newNow.getTime();

      var hour = Math.floor(distance / 1000 / 60 / 60); 
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      if (hour < 1 && minutes < 1 && seconds < 2) {
        this.setState({isClosed: false});
      } else {
        this.setState({
          textt: hour + ' h ' + minutes + ' m ' + seconds + 's',
        });
      }
    }, 1000); 
  }
```

}

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this._interval);
    clearTimeout(this._interval);
  }


if (!this._interval) {
      console.log('this._interval',this._interval)
```

and `console log =  this._interval null`

Comment: It continues for a while after you navigate into another page or continues forever? Anyway, 300 ms is not realistic and set a setInterval to 1000 ms does not implies that it start exactly after 1 sec (even if 3 sec seems too much)... maybe you see the state updated after 3 sec (but also this is normal considering that this.setState is async)

Comment: maybe you see the state updated after 3 sec.  I think so too . and also yes continues forever. WHat should i change

Comment: @giovanni-esposito thank you for helping me.It gave me some improment

Comment: Happy to help you. Have a nice coding =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using react-navigation stacknavigator won‘t call`componentdidmount`  when pushing a new view on top.

As you can see in [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/), you should rather subscribe to focus/blur.

Comment: SOrry i can't get it exactly. Also i got focus code     this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
 
    });

Comment: this.props.navigation.addListener('blur', () => { }) will be fired when you navigate to a new screen.

That is probably what you want to archive with componentWillUnmount.

Comment: Well thank you using bulur like focus works fine but i must add the interval function also in focus section. Thank you.